# Run Anylogic with a different JRE

Tags: java, anylogic

The Anylogic installation package (v. 8.2.3) includes JRE (Java version 9.0.1).

I need to run Anylogic with a different JRE (Java 8)

Is this possible?

Comment: Not likely, if the artifact has been compiled for and is running on Java 9+.  You can't run newer artifacts on older VMs.

Comment: What happens when you set `JAVA_HOME` before running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. AnyLogic uses built-in JRE, located in AnyLogic installation folder. At Windows it looks like this: `C:\Program Files\AnyLogic 8 Professional\jre`

You can install Oracle JRE and copy its `jre1.8.0_...` folder in AnyLogic installation folder. Rename the existing `jre` to `jre_9`, `jre1.8...` to `jre`. Launch AnyLogic, it will use the respective JRE.